(Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed
I've the following configuration in my standalone.xml file:
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:14.0" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-server="default-        server" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.undertow.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}" default-security-domain="other">
493             <byte-buffer-pool name="default"/>
494             <buffer-cache name="default"/>
495             <server name="default-server">
496                 <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
497                 <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" ssl-context="demoSSLContext" enable-http2="true"/>
498                 <host name="default-host" alias="itcmedbr.com,www.itcmedbr.com">
499                     <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
500                     <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
501                     <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
502                     <http-invoker http-authentication-factory="application-http-authentication"/>
503                 </host>
504             </server>
505             <servlet-container name="default">
506                 <jsp-config/>
507                 <websockets/>
508             </servlet-container>
509             <handlers>
510                 <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
511             </handlers>
512             <application-security-domains>
513                 <application-security-domain name="other" security-domain="ApplicationDomain"/>
514             </application-security-domains>
515         </subsystem>

and I've nginx.conf to configure proxy_pass:
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;

        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

    server {
    listen 80 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:80 ssl http2;

    server_name itcmedbr.com; # managed by Certbot
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
            resolver itcmedbr.com [::1]:5353;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_pass http://itcmedbr.com:80;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/itcmedbr.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/itcmedbr.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

    server {
    if ($host = itcmedbr.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}}

but I am receiving the following error:
2024-04-26 08:47:55,344 INFO  [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 104) Initializing Mojarra 4.0.5 for context '/itcmedbr'
2024-04-26 08:48:04,281 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 104) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/itcmedbr' for server 'default-server'
2024-04-26 08:48:06,262 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("host" => "default-host"),
    ("filter-ref" => "server-header")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.filter.server-header"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["service jboss.undertow.server.default-server.default-host.filter-ref.server-header is missing [jboss.undertow.filter.server-header]"]
}
2024-04-26 08:48:06,270 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("host" => "default-host"),
    ("filter-ref" => "x-powered-by-header")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.filter.x-powered-by-header"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["service jboss.undertow.server.default-server.default-host.filter-ref.x-powered-by-header is missing [jboss.undertow.filter.x-powered-by-header]"]
}
2024-04-26 08:48:06,697 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "itcmedbr.war" (runtime-name : "itcmedbr.war")
2024-04-26 08:48:06,797 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.undertow.filter.server-header (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.server.default-server.default-host.filter-ref.server-header]
      service jboss.undertow.filter.x-powered-by-header (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.server.default-server.default-host.filter-ref.x-powered-by-header]

2024-04-26 08:48:07,469 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server

The error show server, host and filter-ref in the operation ("add") but I already defined this in standalone.xml file.
When I type itcmedbr.com on the browser the nginx welcome page is loaded with View site information button but if I type itcmedbr.com:80 I received that " This site can't provide a secure connection".
I appreciate any assistance, thanks.
